# Jquery ui autocomplete driving me crazy

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a `<input id="txtCustome2r" />`

I have in my `.ready` function

```
$("#txtCustome2r").autocomplete({
    source:  "itemcomplete.asp", 
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
                     "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                     "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
    }
});
```

the auto complete return valid json

```
[ { "id': "4",  "label": "Kathi  ",   "value": "Kathi  "}, { "id': "6",  "label": "Kathleen  ",   "value": "Kathleen  "}]
```

and nothing shows up in the drop down. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Single quotes are not valid JSON. You'll need to surround your key names and string values with double quotes:

```
[ { "id": 4,  "label": "Kathi", "value": "Kathi 3" }, ... ]
```

If you want to check your JSON response for validity, you can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: no, unfortunately not. I updated it to double quotes. Still no dice.

Comment: ok no it workeD! can you remove the last names from your answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still having problems after verifying your format as mentioned in @Mark Bell's solution, try passing in `dataType: 'json'` to the autocomplete function call.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a little tricky.  I like making the source a function so I can have more control.  Notice the override on toString:

```
var search = function (request, response) {
    jQuery.get(
        jQuery('#SearchUrl').val(),
        { searchString: request.term },
        function (data) {
            response(jQuery.map(data.searchResults, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.Id,
                    value: {
                        toString: function () { return item.Id + ' - ' + item.Name; },
                        Name: item.Name
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
    );
};
// set up the autocomplete
jQuery('#MyTextBox').autocomplete({
    source: search,
    minLength: 3,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        jQuery('#name').text(ui.item.value.Name);
    }
});
```